# Can I modify an object stored in a react state hook without having to duplicate that object?

Tags: javascript, react-hooks

Let's say I have a code scenario like this....

```
const obj = {
   dogs: ["terrier", "labrador", "poodle"],
   ages: [4,6,11],
   names: ["Fido", "Max", "Spot"]
};

const [data, setData] = useState(obj);
```

Then, I want to change one of the names in the array to Richard, for example. How can I do this efficiently?

What I've been doing is cloning the object with `let clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))` then modifying the clone, then calling `setData(clone)`. I feel like there has got to be a better way though where I don't have to clone the object.

Comment: If you don't clone the object React doesn't know that you have updated state since it is checked by reference equality

Comment: that being said the `JSON` approach isn't best, and a deep clone is unnecessary. A shallow copy of the containing object, and a clone of any mutated nested objects is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't clone the object React doesn't know that you have updated state since it is checked by reference equality. That being said the `JSON` approach isn't great, see [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) for full discussion.

But a deep clone is not actually necessary in this situation; a shallow copy of the containing object, and a clone of any mutated nested objects is sufficient. Here is an example updating the nested `dogs` array using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to clone the object and `map()` to update the necessary nested array.

```
const obj = {
  dogs: ["terrier", "labrador", "poodle"],
  ages: [4, 6, 11],
  names: ["Fido", "Max", "Spot"],
};

const [data, setData] = useState(obj);

const updateDogs = (oldValue, newValue) =>
  setData(prevData => ({
    ...prevData,
    dogs: prevData.dogs.map(dog => (dog === oldValue ? newValue : dog)),
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to split it into 3 state values:

```
const [dogs, setDogs] = useState(["terrier", "labrador", "poodle"]);
const [ages, setAges] = useState([4,6,11]);
const [names, setNames] = useState(["Fido", "Max", "Spot"]);
```

To change a name, you can then clone the `names` collection (instead of the entire object) and update that:

```
const newNames = [...names];
newNames[someIndex] = theNewName;
setNames(newNames);
```

To me this makes it much clearer that only a certain part of the state is being updated, and it eliminates the risk of inadvertent changes to other parts of the state.

Also it is more efficient, although for such a small dataset the difference will not be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

As pilchard commented you need to do a copy to trigger a change, but you can do with the new deep clone:

```
let clone = structuredClone(obj);
```